# ¿como actualizar un select después de consultarlo al igual que los option?. Necesito ayuda no me esta funcionando esta forma

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php 
 include ("conexion.php");
//Mostrar Datos
              if(empty($_GET ['id']))
              {

                header('location: consultarform.php');
              }
              $iduser = $_GET ['id'];
              $sql= mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT  Estatus,Apellido, Nombre, Fecha, Sexo, Edad, Promovido,telefono FROM alumnos WHERE id= $iduser");

              $result_sql = mysqli_num_rows ($sql);
              if ($result_sql == 0) {
                header('location:consultarform.php');

              } else

                 {

                  while ($data= mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    # code...

                      $Estatus = $data ['Estatus'];
                      $Apellido = $data ['Apellido'];
                      $Nombre = $data ['Nombre'];
                      $sexo = $data ['Sexo'];
                      $Edad = $data ['Edad'];
                    $promovido = $data ['Promovido'];
                      $fecha = $data ['Fecha'];
                      $telefono = $data ['telefono'];
                  }

                     }


  ?>
```

---

```
  <input type="text"  name="Nombres_Estudiante" placeholder="&#128102; Escriba su nombre(s) ֍" class="input-48" required  value="<?php  echo $Nombre; ?>">

//Este es mi problema

   <cite>Seleccione el Sexo</cite>
<label class="container" >M
  <input type="radio"  name="sexo" id="Radio1" value="<?php  echo $sexo; ?>" > 
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">F
  <input type="radio"  name="sexo" id="Radio2"  value="<?php  echo $sexo; ?>">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>


<select name="Estatus"  class="input-24" required style="color: red; font-size: 14px;font-weight:bold;"    >

<option value="" disabled selected >ESTATUS DEL ESTUDIANTE ֍</option>

          <option value="<?php  echo $Estatus; ?>">RE-ISCRIPCION</option>
          <option value="<?php  echo $Estatus; ?>" >INSCRIPCION</option>

     </select>
```

Comment: estas repitiendo `<?php  echo $Estatus; ?>` para ambos values

Comment: lo que sucede es que la variable es  $Estatus;
$Estatus = $data ['Estatus'];    
que asuvez contien el valor en la base de Datos RE-ISNCRIPCION E  INSCRIPCION,
y aunque lo coloco una sola vez no presenta la información 
te recuerdo que es un select, pero en imput text me funciona

Comment: veo que es un select, que valores toma? de donde los toma?

Comment: La forma tradicional lo lo coloco en Html, lo conecto con php a la base de datos y luego hago la petición a la base de datos ya guardados,  pero no se consultarlo para editarlo. Lo tomo de una base de datos, arriba explico el código de que forma lo transfiero de la base de datos a la variable. Pero no se presentarlo para que reciba la informacion ya guardada para editarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La estructura general de un `<Select>` es la siguiente:

```
<SELECT name="NombreDelCampoParaGuardarElValor">
 <OPTION value="PrimerValorDelSelect">Texto que se muestra para el primer valor</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="SegundoValorDelSelect">Texto que se muestra para el segundo valor</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="TercerValorDelSelect" selected="selected">Texto que se muestra para el tercer valor</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Fijate que la tercer `OPTION` tiene el atributo `selected` eso hará que sea la opción seleccionada, y el valor de  `NombreDelCampoParaGuardarElValor` será igual a su `value`es decir  `TercerValorDelSelect`

En tu código no queda muy claro cuales son los valores de las options asi que va medio generico:

```
<?php 
  $valorOption1 = "RE-ISCRIPCION";
  $valorOption2 = "INSCRIPCION";
?>
<select name="Estatus"  class="input-24" required style="color: red; font-size: 14px;font-weight:bold;"    >
  <option 
    value="" disabled selected >ESTATUS DEL ESTUDIANTE ֍</option>

  <option value="<?php echo $valorOption1; ?>" 
     <?php echo ($Estatus==$valorOption1)?'selected="selected"':''; ?>
     >RE-ISCRIPCION</option>

  <option value="<?php echo $valorOption2; ?>" 
     <?php echo ($Estatus==$valorOption2)?'selected="selected"':''; ?>
    >INSCRIPCION</option>
 </select>
```

en cada option verificas si `$Estatus` es igual al `$valorOption` y si son iguales imprimis el `selected`

Comment: Gracias mil me funciono tal y cual me lo enviaste,  ya entendí el funcionamiento de los select y la base de datos gracias a ti mil.