# Cual es la mejor forma de establecer un valor de un dropdown desde la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, dropdownlist

Tengo un dropdown de tipo de sangre, y los valores estan hardcode, pero al momento de entrar a la interfaz, cual es la mejor forma de establecer el valor previamente guardado de la base de datos, estoy haciendo algo como esto:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="'.$key.'" name="'.$key.'">
                        <optgroup label="Grupo A">';
                            $sel = ($value == 'A+') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="A+" '.$sel.'>A positivo</option>';
                            $sel = ($value == 'A-') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="A-" '.$sel.'>A negativo</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Grupo B">';
                            $sel = ($value == 'B+') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="B+" '.$sel.'>B positivo</option>';
                            $sel = ($value == 'B-') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="B-" '.$sel.'>B negativo</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Grupo AB">';
                            $sel = ($value == 'AB+') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="AB+" '.$sel.'>AB positivo</option>';
                            $sel = ($value == 'AB-') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="AB-" '.$sel.'>AB negativo</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Grupo O">';
                            $sel = ($value == 'O+') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="O+" '.$sel.'>O positivo</option>';
                            $sel = ($value == 'O-') ? 'selected' : '' ;
                            echo '<option value="O-" '.$sel.'>O negativo</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        </select>
```

Cual es la mejor forma de poner el atributo "selected" a un option de un select con un valor desde una base de datos?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿como actualizar un select después de consultarlo al igual que los option?. Necesito ayuda no me esta funcionando esta forma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162350/como-actualizar-un-select-despu%c3%a9s-de-consultarlo-al-igual-que-los-option-nece)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien vas a tener los valores hardcodeados, podes almacenarlos en un array e iterarlo para que sea mas sencillo de modificar y de leer, ademas de usar interpolacion de strings en lugar de concatenaciones para escribir menos codigo:

```
<?php

    $grupos = array("Grupo A"  => array( "A+" => "A positivo", "A-" => "A negativo"),
                    "Grupo B"  => array( "B+" => "B positivo", "B-" => "B negativo"),
                    "Grupo AB" => array( "AB+" => "AB positivo", "AB-" => "AB negativo"),
                    "Grupo O"  => array( "O+" => "O positivo", "O-" => "O negativo")
                    );

    echo "<select class='selectpicker' id='$key' name='$key'>";

    foreach( $grupos as $grupo => $tipos){

        echo "<optgroup label='$grupo'>";

        foreach( $tipos as $tipo => $descripcion){

            $sel = ($value == $tipo) ? "selected " : "";

            echo "<option value='$tipo' $sel>$descripcion</option>";
        }

        echo "</optgroup>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero declaras tu combo y haces consulta a la Base de datos y cuando lo llenes de valores puedes validar si coincide el valor de la BD con el valor de tu combo.

```
<?php 

    $sql= "select id,campo_A from tablaSangre= id=21";

        $ress = mysqli_query($Prueba, $sql);   
                  ?>
    <select class="form-control form-control-lg"  id="combo<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" disabled>
    <?php  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)){

        if ($row['id']==$rows['id']) {
            echo " <option id='".$rows[campo_A']."' value='".$rows['campo_A']."' selected>".$rows['campo_A']."</option> ";
        }
        else {        
            echo " <option id='".$rows['campo_A']."' value='".$rows['campo_A']."' >".$rows['campo_A']."</option> ";
            }} ?>       
        </select><br>

  </div>
```

Saludos cordiales,